# C++: having problems with instantiation of func template

Tags: c++, templates

I am working on a project which includes class and function templates, which I wrote.
when compiling i'm having this error:

```
SNN.h In function `void KNN(const std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> >&, std::vector<Cluster<T, K>, std::allocator<Cluster<T, K> > >&) [with T = int, unsigned int K = 5u]':
```

followed by this errors (i think they're connected):

```
1)instantiated from `void ClusteringExample() [with T = int]'
2)instantiated from here:ClusteringExample<int>();
3)SNN.h [Warning] comparing floating point with == or != is unsafe
**4) conversion from `<unknown type>' to non-scalar type `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const Product*, std::vector<Product, std::allocator<Product> > >' requested**
```

When ClusteringExampke is the func template. here's it's implementation:

```
template <typename T>
void ClusteringExample()
    {
        std::vector<T> T_input;
        std::vector<Cluster<T,cluster_size> > clusters_T;
        FillVector( T_input, count_per_line );
        SNN( T_input, clusters_T);
        for (typename std::vector<Cluster<T,cluster_size> >::size_type i=0;       
    i<clusters_T.size(); i++ )
        {
            clusters_T[i].Print();
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout  << "===="<< std::endl; 
    }
```

code of KNN:
**

```
void  KNN( const std::vector<T>& all_items, std::vector<Cluster<T,K> >& result )
{
     result.clear(); 
     if ( K > all_items.size() ) return; //we cannot create clusters bigger than the number of all items
     //for each item in all_items we will create a cluster
     for (typename std::vector<T>::size_type i=0; i < all_items.size(); i++ )
     {
         //this vector will save distances to the item i
         std::vector<double> distances;
         //passing over all items and calculating distance to the item i
         for (typename std::vector<T>::size_type j=0; j < all_items.size(); j++ )
         {
             distances.push_back( Distance(all_items[i], all_items[j] ));
         }
          //creating new cluster
         Cluster<T,K> new_cluster;
         //we are looking for K nearest distances
         std::sort( distances.begin(), distances.end() );
         for ( std::vector<double>::size_type d=0; d<K; d++ )
         {
              for (typename std::vector<T>::size_type j=0; j < all_items.size(); j++ )
               {
                  if (Distance(all_items[i], all_items[j] ) == distances[d] ) //every item which is closer then the "farest" is added to the cluster
                  {
                     new_cluster.Add( all_items[j] ); //we don't use the return value of Add in this implementation, but you need to support it
                  }
               }
         }
         result.push_back( new_cluster );
```

**
Have to say: it is happening for all types i'm trying to instantiate for (int,double and a class type).
This error is not much informative to me.
Anyone has a clue for where the problem can be?

Comment: You've only provided part of the error message...

Comment: I added a warning massage which was after the first two error messages.

Comment: You're missing the error message itself.

Comment: Looks like a problem with `T_input` somewhere, what's the signature of `FillVector`? Could you provide the full list of errors please.

Comment: I wish i could, it a long list. I'll add some more error lines. Hope it'll make it clearer.

Comment: Can you show also the code of `KNN()` please, the error message refers to it.

Comment: signature of FILLVector(): template <typename T>
void FillVector( std::vector<T>& to_fill, size_t count)
{

Comment: Compiler? OS? We need more information.

Comment: compiler- dev c++ op-windows..and i just added error message(no.4)

Comment: Can you mark the line provided with the primary error message please.

Comment: template<typename T, size_t K> void Cluster<T,K>::Print() const
{
    for(typename vector<T>::const_iterator iter=_cluster_vec.begin;iter!=_cluster_vec.end();++iter)
    {
        cout<<(*iter)<<" ";
    }
}  @g-makulik, the 4th error points on the for loop line

Comment: So that means the primary error line is not shown in the code you posted (I can't spot it at least)?? Could it be that `SNN` is meant to be called only with types of `std::vector<Cluster<double,K> >`?

Answer (score 2):

If you really have this code:

```
template<typename T, size_t K> void Cluster<T,K>::Print() const {
  for(typename vector<T>::const_iterator iter=_cluster_vec.begin;iter!=_cluster_vec.end();++iter) {
    cout<<(*iter)<<" "; 
  }
}
```

Then (a) you need to change `begin` to `begin()` and (b) you would have got an answer sooner if you'd posted the code with the error in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `Distance(all_items[i], all_items[j] ) == distances[d]` might have surprising effects some times... You should never compare floating point numbers (`float` or `double`) for equality or inequality.

I recommend that you read the IEEE 754 standard and google for *double equality comparison* to get more information.

Additionally, the comparison and the comment do not seem to go hand by hand, you are comparing equality but the comment claims:

```
//every item which is closer then the "farest" is added to the cluster
```

Maybe you meant `<=`?

Comment: @david-rodriguez-dribeas thanks for the answer but the KNN is a given code which cannot be changed. I believe that my core problen connected to error no.4 or to definition of the func template.